# RangeError (index): Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, api

I am trying to display data from an api in a ListView.builder, I want to set the itemCount to 20 but when I do that, before the data is displayed I get the following error ***RangeError (index): Valid value range is empty: 0*** the '0' is incremented in each card until '20'. If anyone can help me, thanks.

````
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:banner_carousel/banner_carousel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:kaomini/Pages/accueil.dart';
import 'package:kaomini/Pages/detail_article.dart';
import 'package:kaomini/Pages/panier.dart';
import 'package:kaomini/widgets/drawer_menu.dart';
import 'package:kaomini/widgets/images.dart';

class PromoArticle extends StatefulWidget {
  const PromoArticle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _PromoArticleState createState() => _PromoArticleState();
}

class _PromoArticleState extends State<PromoArticle> {
  List userdata = [];
  int _count = 20;
  Future<void> getrecord() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        My api;

    try {
      var response = await http.get(
        uri,
      );
      setState(() {
        userdata = jsonDecode(response.body);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void increment(){
    setState((){
      _count = _count + 10;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getrecord();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black, size: 33.0),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shadowColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 19.0),
            child: Badge(
                badgeColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                badgeContent: Text("${Panier.art.length}"),
                animationType: BadgeAnimationType.fade,
                child: IconButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Panier(products: <Product> [
                      //Product(nom: widget.mail, mail: widget.mail)
                    ],)
                )
                ),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined))),
          )
        ],
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
            child: const Text("Produits en promo",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.blue
              ),
            ),
          ),
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
            GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount: userdata == null ? 0 : _count,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                debugPrint(userdata[index]['photo'].toString());
                return userdata == null ? const Center(child: Text('Aucune donnees !'),)
                    : GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => DetailArticle(
                        id: userdata[index]['id'],
                        titre: userdata[index]['title'],
                        description: userdata[index]['description'],
                        prix: userdata[index]['realPrice'],
                        image: userdata[index]['pictures'],
                        prixPromo: userdata[index]["discountPrice"],
                        //.toString() == null ?
                        //"https://www.kaomini.ne/uploads/images/logo.png" :
                        //userdata[index]['photo'],
                      )
                  )
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        //Image.network(userdata[index]['photo'].toString()),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: userdata[index]["pictures"] == null ? MyAssetImage.logo1 :
                          Image.network("https://kaomini.ne/uploads/productPictures/"+userdata[index]["pictures"]),//MyAssetImage.img2
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListTile(
                            enabled: false,
                            title: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Text(userdata[index]["discountPrice"]+' FCFA',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        fontSize: 17.0
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(userdata[index]["realPrice"],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        fontSize: 15.0
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(userdata[index]["title"],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  fontSize: 15.0
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

            ElevatedButton(onPressed: increment,
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: const Size(400, 50),
                    primary: Colors.blue[100],
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),)
                ),
                child: const Text("Voir plus", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),)
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      endDrawer: const MyMenu(),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Comment: How many items does your api return before increment ?

Comment: Don't call `getrecord()` from `initState`, because the `build` method will run earlier than your future is complete. Instead use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and return `userdata` from it.

Comment: @DanielRoldán It returns 20

Comment: @PeterKoltai When I display Text('${snapshot.data}') it displays all the json

Comment: @PeterKoltai `Future<dynamic> getrecord() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        'https://tops-rifle.000webhostapp.com/planning/getPromo.php'); //"https://tops-rifle.000webhostapp.com/planning/getPost.php";

    try {
      var response = await http.get(
        uri,
      );
      setState(() {
        userdata = jsonDecode(response.body);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return userdata;
  }`

Comment: That's fine, but this will be executed later than the `build` method where you need it. With the `FutureBuilder` I referred to you can solve it and you don't need `setState`.

Comment: I have the same thing without the setState

Comment: It's ok, I put the GridView.builder in the FutureBuilder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
itemCount: userdata == null ? 0 : _count,
```

to

```
itemCount: userdata.isEmpty ? 0 : _count,
```

or

```
itemCount: userdata.length,
```

Comment: It's ok, I put the GridView.builder in the FutureBuilder. Thanks